# PonyORM/Postgres multi-tenancy options

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, multi-tenant, ponyorm

I have an application running in production that I've built for a single client that I want to convert to support multiple "tenants".

Currently I am using a Postgres database where all my data resides in a single database in the default `public` schema. I would like to isolate each tenant to a separate Postgres schema. Ideally, my application's UI would make a call to my API using the tenant's subdomain. In `before_request` I would somehow be able to set all database queries during the current request context to only query that tenant's schema, is this possible?

I envisage an ideal solution to be something similar to this contrived example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pony.orm import Database, Required

app = Flask(__name__)
db = Database(**{<db_connection_dict>})

class User(db.Entity):
  email = Required(str)
  password = Required(str)

  @classmethod
  def login(cls, email: str, password: str) -> str:
    user = cls.get(lambda u: u.email.lower() == email.lower())
    if not user:
      return None
    password_is_valid = <method_to_check_hashed_pasword>
    if not password_is_valid:
      return None
    return <method_to_generate_jwt>

db.generate_mapping()

@app.before_request
def set_tenant():
  tenant_subdomain = request.host.split(".")[0]
  // MISSING STEP.. set_schema is a fictitous method, does something similar to this exist?
  db.set_schema(schema=tenant_subdomain)??

@app.route("auth/login", methods=["POST"]
def login_route():
  data = request.get_json()
  jwt = User.login(data["email"], data["password"])
  if not jwt:
   return make_response({}, 403)
  return make_response(jsonify(data=jwt), 200)
```

I've come across an interesting/simple [example](https://gist.github.com/TonyFrancis/7bfa8ac5f699da3c57f282c2ac7ff0a7) using SQLAlchemy. If not possible with PonyORM I may consider porting my models over to SQLAlchemy but would miss the simplicity of Pony :(

I thought about possibly using the [`Database.on_connect`](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#Database.on_connect) method to do something as such but not sure if if anyone has any other ideas or if this would even work properly in production. I suspect not because if I had two separate tenants querying the database they would overwrite the search path..

```py
@db.on_connect()
def set_request_context_tenant_schema(db, connection) -> None:
    subdomain = request.host.split(".")[0]
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SET search_path TO {subdomain}, public;")
```

Comment: Do you want to specify schema name for each table? Or you want some entity to produce several tables in several schemas?

Comment: Ideally the models/tables would be  « flexible » (ie. the tables would exist, cloned, in multiple schemas). Anytime a new tenant joins an accompanying pg schema would be created for them, along with all the tables.